# Do hierachical models sometimes give narrower CIs for fixed-level effects?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

My limited understanding of modelling has been that in most cases hierarchical models give wider CI-s, meaning that they give more conservative results.

However, to my surprise, when playing with different data and models, I sometimes see the opposite: the width of fixed-level intercept is narrower compared to a non-hierarchical model.

**For example, CIs for the fixed-level intercept are narrower for model B compared to model A:**

Model A: `y ~ 1 + school`

Model B: `y ~ 1 + (1 | school)`

I tried to figure out the reason. May it be so that if there are data with a lot of different schools informs our model more, incorporates shrinkage, and gives narrower CIs? And vice versa: data with only a few schools with varying mean y values widens our CIs in a hierarchical model? Could you please comment on that?

Comment: This is a statistical question, not a coding one, so it's more appropriate to post it on CrossValidated instead. That said, for Model B, the effect of school is estimated with partial pooling, so the difference of each school from the overall mean will be slightly smaller than in Model A, which explains the difference in the uncertainty regarding the intercept, provided that you've used sum coding.

Comment: Would you mind providing the software you used to fit these models? There are several ways to fit fixed effects models that change the interpretation of the intercept. For example, if you just included the school variable as a factor, the intercept is the mean outcome for the reference school, whereas, in the random effects model, the intercept is the average of the school mean outcomes (shrunken). So this could just be a difference in interpretation, and that estimating quantities with the same interpretation yields more comparable results.